# How to debug ARC deleting an object when it shouldn't

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a case in my iOS game (compiled with ARC) where an object (ivar, NSMutableDictionary) is being deleted in the Release build when it clearly shouldn't be.  In the Debug build, everything is fine.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to debug this.  If I put any kind of checks against the object, it hangs around as it should.  I know the object is being used because the App crashes, so the objects is being accessed.

I used Zombie objects to tell that the object is being deleted, but I don't know where and when it is happening.

Is there a way for me to see when the compiler thinks this objects is not longer needed or when it is actually being delete (which might not tell me anything if it's in the autorelease pool).

Does anyone have good advice to tracking this down?  I reluctant to just call this a compiler bug, but I can't see how the compiler could think this object is not referenced anymore since it's referenced all over the place.  The object that holds the ivar is where all my code is being run, so it is clearly still around (and much worse things would be happening if it wasn't).

For now I'm just going to leave that one line of debugging code in that causes the object to not be deleted, but I hate to ship the App with that solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any further information on this issue? I just ran into a crash when compiling with any optimization other than -O0 that deals with ARC deleting an object it should be retaining...

Comment: The bug went a way for me when xcode updated, so I assume it was a compiler issue.  That was 9 months ago and I've had to issues since.

Comment: OK thanks. Turns out it was a strange issue that went away when I made a CGPoint a property instead of merely a member of an Objective-C class. Strange, but at least the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The place to put your debugging code is in the `dealloc` method of the object. You can put a breakpoint here (even in Release mode) and see at what point its going away.

The most likely cause is that some piece of code is being either re-ordered or eliminated in Release.

When you say "it's referenced all over the place," do you mean that you have objects that are holding a strong reference to it in their properties? The first rule of memory management is to retain (put in an ivar) what you care about, and release what you no longer care about. If you have objects that care about this object, then they should have a strong property pointing to it. If they do, then it should certainly not go away.

---

Dangling strong pointers under ARC suggests a serious problem in your code. I would start by looking for anywhere you have use a bridging cast (`__bridge` in particular). Make sure you're not handing objects to void pointers incorrectly.

Watch for any use of C arrays. If you walk off the end of a C array, then you can corrupt other memory, which can cause these kinds of problems.

Similarly watch any use of anything that takes a `length` argument such as in `NSString` and `NSData`. If you pass too long a value, you can walk off the end of data and corrupt other variables. Similarly anything with raw pointers via `malloc` memory.

Comment: The object in question is a NSMutableDictionary and it's held in one ivar, but it is referenced all over my code, so I find it hard to believe the compiler thought it was not used anymore. I'll try subclassing it so I can put a breakpoint in the dealloc.  If the compiler thinks it's not used anymore and is deleting it, I don't know what do do about that, since ARC is just some compiler magic.  It feels odd if we have to kludge around something like this that seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: Well, that's easier said then done.  You can't just subclass NSMutableDictionary without a lot of hoop jumping. Is there an easier way to break on the dealloc of a NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: Sorry; I missed that the object was a dictionary. Subclassing that would radically change it (it wouldn't be a tollfree bridge class anymore). But the fact that code "references" the dictionary has nothing to do with whether it has strong references to it. If it's in a strong ivar, it should live. If it's not, it can go away at any time. If it's going away while it's in an ivar, then you're probably wrong about it being in that ivar, and you should dig into why it actually isn't in the ivar when you think it is.

Comment: There are other kinds of strong references that aren't ivars BTW. But they only apply while the pointer is in scope.

Comment: It is stored in an ivar.  I am certain of that.  `myivar = [NSMutableDictionary new]` is only place this variable is set and I am certain it is an ivar.  ivars are strong by default, so I don't know what else to do.  This code has been working correctly for months.

Comment: If you have a strong ivar, it's not going to become nil on its own. Either the owning object is being deallocated, or the ivar is being set to nil. You could add a gdb watchpoint to see when that happens. If you would switch to accessors (which you should do; don't mess with ivars directly), then you could use KVO to see when the value changes.

Comment: The ivar is not being set to nil, the object it points to is being deleted.  I access the ivar directly because I'm running code in that class.  The ivar is being set within the object and accessed within the object, there is no @property for the ivar since it's never accessed outside the class it belongs to.

Comment: So you crash when you dereference the ivar? It's dangling? If you hae a dangling strong pointer, you do have a serious bug (are you mixing MRC and ARC code?). BTW, you should use accessors even inside the class. You can and should declare private properties. It avoids a lot of problems (fewer now that we have ARC, but still quite a few).

Comment: I am not mixing ARC with MRC, and yes, it is a dangling strong pointer.  Something is very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a problem today which sounds just like what you've run into here. We are loading a class using a custom method from an NSDictionary loaded from a plist file and our app now crashes at the end of that method due to, what looks like, a double release. We found that turning off the optimisation of the release binary was all that we could do to fix it.

We haven't changed any related code to the method which is now causing the crash (it has been running fine for about 2 months), and after many hours of trying to figure out where the problem was we found that the only way we can fix it at the moment is to change 'Optimization Level' to 'None' for our release code. Go to..

Project -> Targets -> Binary Name -> Build Settings -> Optimization Level -> Release

And set it to 'None -O0'.

I can only presume that there is a very strange bug which is occurring in the optimiser, but I hope this helps you!

Comment: After a lot of investigation, I'm convinced my problem is a compiler issue.  I just installed xcode 4.3, so I need to go back and see if this persists.  If it does I should file a Apple bug for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening to me as well, but with weak IBOutlets.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *blahView;

…

[self.blahView removeFromSuperview];
[self.otherView addSubview:self.blahView];
```

After the first line compiler thinks there are no more references to the object and releases / nils it out.

Keeping the weak reference ivar and using a temporary variable (in scope) to do this convinces the compiler to not release it.

```
UIView *blahView = self.blahView;
[blahView removeFromSuperview];
[self.otherView addSubview:blahView];
```

Does that solve your problem?